# GREP with wildcard, but exclude a specific term and return file name

Tags: regex, string, grep, filenames

I'm new to using grep and I would need to perform quite a complicated query so here goes:

I would like to recursively grep into a directory for the string:  `====\d+` 
where \d+ is one or more decimals (perl syntax) and the string is different than `====0`.

I want the grep to return the file name of the file containing the `====\d+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show only the file names without their paths, you could do

```
grep -ERl '====[1-9]\d*' . | while read name; do basename $name; done
```

Or, if your file names can contain spaces, newlines or other strangeness, use

```
grep -ZERl '====[1-9]\d*' . | while IFS= read -r -d '' name; do 
    basename "$name"; 
done
```

The `grep` flags used are (from GNU `grep`'s manual):

```
   -E, --extended-regexp
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  an extended regular expression (ERE, see
          below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)
   -R, --dereference-recursive
          Read all files under each directory,  recursively.   Follow  all
          symbolic links, unlike -r.
   -l, --files-with-matches
          Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print the name of each input
          file from which output would normally have  been  printed.   The
          scanning  will  stop  on  the  first match.  (-l is specified by
          POSIX.)
   -Z, --null
          Output  a  zero  byte  (the  ASCII NUL character) instead of the
          character that normally follows a file name.  For example,  grep
          -lZ  outputs  a  zero  byte  after each file name instead of the
          usual newline.  This option makes the output  unambiguous,  even
          in the presence of file names containing unusual characters like
          newlines.  This option can  be  used  with  commands  like  find
          -print0,  perl  -0,  sort  -z, and xargs -0 to process arbitrary
          file names, even those that contain newline characters.
```

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to try:

```
grep -rle "====[1-9][0-9]*" /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
grep -rle '====[1-9][0-9]*' /path/to/files
```

where:

```
-r recurse into the directory (and sub-directories)
-l only list files
-e use regexp
```

The regexp will match four equal symbols, followed by a digit greater than zero, then zero or more other digits.

Comment: -e actually turns on *extended* regular expressions, which aren't actually needed for this.

Comment: is there a way to not display the full directory in which the file name is located? and just the file-name by itself?

Comment: @JesseWatZ nope, `-E` if for extended; thx for the `-r` edit, i did miss the request for recursion

Comment: @sSmacKk you can use `basename \`grep -rle '====[1-9][0-9]*' /path/to/files\``

Comment: @guido -- Ah, you are correct. Quoting the man page: -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
              Use PATTERN as the pattern.   This  can  be  used  to  specify  multiple  search
              patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen (-).  (-e is specified
              by POSIX.)